# Advantages of Custom Collaborative Objects over CollaborativeMap?

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

From reading the docs, and my experience using the 4 built-in collaborative types, these possible advantages come to mind:

1. If you prefer to have the realtime functionality mixed into your classes, rather than using composition (class contains a Collaborative* field; this is what I'm doing now).
2. Some of the usual advantages of constructors, with the initializer hook, to ensure that all objects of the class satisfy some property.
3. Some of the usual advantages of typed objects over untyped ones. It seems you cannot write to fields that you haven't registered, so no bugs caused by mistyping a CollaborativeMap key, or accidentally assigning to a key that was meant for a different CollaborativeMap of a different informal type. The latter has happened to me. If I understand correctly, one could preclude both such bugs statically when using Typescript or Flow.
4. The [onLoaded hook](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/custom-objects#the_onloaded_hook). It's not clear to me why something like this isn't available for the built-in types. Can it be simulated for the built-in types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two functionally equivalent (a custom collaborative object is implemented as a CollaborativeMap under the hood), the primary difference is just in the syntax as you point out.

For the onLoaded hook, you can do similar work for built in types in the document [onLoaded function](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/reference/gapi.drive.realtime.html#.load).